# Angular Server Side Rendering and facebook

Tags: angular, facebook, universal

I have implemented **angular universal** using angular 5.

My app consumes an internal `api` with facebook authentication (`ngx-facebook`)

This means that the client side will login the user and provide a `token` to api.Then the api gets the user from token and proceeds according to the request .

The problem is that `ngx-facebook` doesn't support Server Side Rendering  and I can't find any other facebook package  supporting **SSR**.

*Did I miss any package?*
*If not is there any other solution ?*

Comment: Why would you need server-side rendering for dynamic, logged-in-only content?

Comment: Imagine the site is a social platform with posts. 
 Anyone can visit the site and navigate around .  But if he wants to interact he should login . 
All my get requests to api  have optional authentication so I can make the requests.  But if someone is logged in, the response of the get request should provide some extra information (for example If he  can do some actions or write something) . The extra properties determine the display of some divs and classes  So the problem is that  the prerendered display will be   pretty different than the original one  when javascript loads

Comment: _“But if someone is logged in, the response of the get request should provide some extra information (for example If he can do some actions or write something)”_ - what does that have to do with what the share on Facebook should look like? You don’t really want the description on Facebook to say, _“You can edit this or create a new post”_ anyway, right?

Comment: Pre-render what a normal, not logged-in user coming to the page would see - because that will most likely be the case for the average Facebook user that clicks on any of your shares. (Unless you are sharing in specific places only, like say a group where you can expect the majority of users to have an account on your page already.)

Comment: Example: If someone can write content  then a textarea is displayed. The default behavior is the textarea to exist for non-logged users. But  if someone is logged In and has write some content he can t write again.So I have pre-render a textarea. Imagine you visit my site. You see a pre renderered textarea and after 1-2 sec (while browser downloads javascript) magic happens and you don t watch it now .